# Convert specific humidity into relative humidity in R or CDO for gridded data

Tags: r, raster, cdo-climate

How can I implement the code in the package [Humidity](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/humidity/humidity.pdf) to convert specific humidity into relative humidity using gridded time series data? The required input variables are air temperature, specific humidity and pressure.

Although a solution in CDO is highly desirable, a computationally efficient solution in R will suffice.

Given that the actual data size per variable is >10GB, computational efficiency would be helpful.

**Sample data:**

```
library(raster)
library(humidity)

temperature <- brick(nl=10)
values(temperature ) <- 273.15

pressure<- brick(nl=10)
values(pressure) <- 101325

specific_humidity<-brick(nl=10)
values(specific_humidity) <- 0.0002153928
```

The function of interest in the `Humidity` package is `SH2RH`. The raw code is found in [this link](https://github.com/caijun/humidity/blob/master/R/humidity.R) and the constants can be sourced from [here](https://github.com/caijun/humidity/blob/master/R/constant.R).

In the end I will write the output to file in `NETCDF` format.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is in a data.frame or comparable format and it has columns for specific humidity (spec_humidity), temperature (temp), and pressure (press) at each time/location, then the following would work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(humidity)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(rel_humidity = SH2RH(q = spec_humidity,   # or whatever the SH data is called
                              t = temp,            # or whatever the temperature data is called
                              p = press,           # or whatever the pressure data is called
                              isK = TRUE))         # or isK = FALSE is temp in degrees C
```

A faster version for your large file might be found in the `dtplyr` package, which uses data.tables (but otherwise the same notation as `dplyr`).

```
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(humidity)
df <- lazy_dt(df)  # convert df into a data.table. The 'lazy' part tracks operations
df <- df %>%
  mutate(rel_humidity = SH2RH(q = spec_humidity,   # same as with dplyr
                              t = temp,           
                              p = press,          
                              isK = TRUE))         # or isK = FALSE is temp in degrees C
```

Finally, there is an experimental `multidplyr` to allow `dplyr` functions to be partitioned over multiple cores. Here is a link to [its documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/multidplyr/versions/0.0.0.9000). You would need to install it from github and not cran (as of posting).

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/multidplyr")
library(multidplyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(humidity)
cluster <- new_cluster(n)   # n is number of cores to devote
df <- df %>% partition(cluster)   # this splits the data over the cores in the cluster
df <- df %>%
  mutate(rel_humidity = SH2RH(q = spec_humidity,   # same as with dplyr, but in parallel
                              t = temp,           
                              p = press,          
                              isK = TRUE)) %>%     # or isK = FALSE is temp in degrees C
  collect()                                        # Brings data back to main host session
```

Comment: Many thanks for offering a solution to my problem.  I am not sure how to format my data to use the above code? In this case I have one `df` for each variable `(df1,df2,df3)`. How do I pass these `dfs` to the code? Can you illustrate the solution using the sample data? In the end I will use the function `rasterFromXYZ` to transform the dataframe (i.e. relative humidity) into a `rasterbrick` and `WriteRaster` to `NETCDF`.

Comment: To compute `rel_humidity`, `SH2RH` uses the same grid point in `spec_humidity`, `temp`, and `press` and so on... for all the grid points.